# Get same value of nasted Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have an object

```
{eno: Object, sc: Object, r: Object}
```

each nested Object contain array example

```
{
    eno :{data:[0,'a','b','3']},
    sc:{data:[0,'a','b','3','f','l']},
    r:{data:[0,'a','b','3','p']},
}
```

the element of each object is dynamic
how can i get same value of each data array element

`same value = [0,'a','b','3']` and if there not any same element `some value ='nope'`

Comment: you can use forEach(), map(), reduce() and other functions to manipulate arrays.

Comment: This is not an array. Arrays dont have keys. And have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823326/find-common-elements-within-dynamic-arrays-object-elements-javascript/44823579#44823579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var commonElements = function(array1, array2) {
  return array1.filter(function(n) {
    return array2.indexOf(n) !== -1;
});
}

var obj = {
    eno :{data:[0,'a','b','3']},
    sc:{data:[0,'a','b','3','f','l']},
    r:{data:[0,'a','b','3','p']},
};

var result = commonElements(obj.eno.data, commonElements(obj.sc.data, obj.r.data)) || 'nope';

console.log('same value :' + result);

/* Solution using map, reduce and filter*/
var res = Object.keys(obj)
.map( o => obj[o].data)
.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)));
console.log('same value :' + res|| 'nope');
```

Comment: thanks hassan, if i combine that with forEach() and array.prototype it running dynamicly... you solve my problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @Alberto Trindade Tavares' answer said, [intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection) of lodash can be used to get the *same value* easily, the code would be very clean. @Alberto Trindade Tavares' answer does not provide a code snippet, and also does not handle the "nope" logic when there is no *same value*. Thus, I'd like to post a working code snippet as below:

```js
var obj = {
    eno :{data:[0,'a','b','3']},
    sc:{data:[0,'a','b','3','f','l']},
    r:{data:[0,'a','b','3','p']},
}

var sameVal = _.intersection(obj.eno.data, obj.sc.data, obj.r.data);
var sameValDisplay = 'Nope';
if (sameVal.length > 0) {
  sameValDisplay = sameVal.toString();
}
console.log('Same value is: ' + sameValDisplay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`intersection` function from `Lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var sameElements = _.intersection(eno.data, sc.data, r.data);
```